# How can I get video.js to play in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, video.js

I've (with help) added the video.js player to a web page and it plays well in all browsers except Firefox. When accessing via Firefox, and trying to play a video I see: "no video with supported format and MIME type found".

Here's my player code:

```
<object class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="640" height="264" type="application/x-  shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
<param name="movie" value="http://url.com/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["[var.base_url]/[var.thumb_file]",  {"url": "http://url.com/uploads/ [var.video_play]","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />
<!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
<img src="[var.base_url]/[var.thumb_file]" width="640" height="264" alt="Poster Image" title="No video playback capabilities." />
</object>
</video>
```

Any suggestions/ideas/remedies will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
<video id="myMovie" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
    <source src="/path/mymovie.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            <source src="/path/mymovie.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

video.js should handle all the necessary fallback nonsense that made embedding videos such a headache back in the day.